# Trouble implementing Material Theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

I am using [this](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/) as a tutorial to implement the Material Theme to an existing app on pre Android 5.0 devices. My problem is that I am getting a `Null Pointer Exception` every-time I call  `getActionBar().something` or `getSupportActionBar().something`.

Here is all I have done to implement the Material Theme.

In values/styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#1A7E99</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#16657A</item>   
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>   
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- View pager progress indecator theme -->
 <style name="StyledIndicators" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>
 </style>

 <style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
    <item name="fillColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name ="strokeWidth">2dp</item> 
    <item name ="strokeColor">#cfd3d4</item>              
    <item name="radius">8dp</item>
    <item name="centered">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget"></style>

<style name="Widget.FloatingHintEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
</style>
```

In my values-v21/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

As I have set the windowActionBar to false, I have a toolbar layout.

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

And finally on to the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION here
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

       // rest of my code
    }
}
```

I am adding my theme in the Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

My Logcat:

```
11-11 12:40:54.798: E/ResourceType(32738): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.driverdesignstudio.drvr/com.driverdesignstudio.drvr.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at com.driverdesignstudio.drvr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:123)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
11-11 12:40:55.349: E/AndroidRuntime(32738):    ... 11 more
```

My questions:

- Why am I getting a Null Pointer Exception for the getActionBar() when I am adding my toolbar layout to the MainActivity?
- How do I add Material design theme to my app.

Cheers,
Rakshak

Comment: Are you using Gradle Build in Android Studio or Eclipse ADT ?

Comment: Eclipse ADT and I have included the AppCompacy Library.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure. I set the "windowActionBar" to true in my theme and commented out the toolbar stuff and the app runs fine. I even get the menu bars to arrow animation that is a part of the AppCompact library.

Comment: Ok so that's not the point. @Dodge seems to be on the right path to solve your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** your actual problem is that you have the `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` code in an own `toolbar.xml` file. this has to be in `activity_main.xml` and all other layouts that you want to use with an actionbar.

---

The Toolbar allows more customization than the default ActionBar (mostly appearance related). If you want or need to customize the actionbar, you need to set a Toolbar as ActionBar. If not. you dont need to do that and you can simply use the default ActionBar provided by the Theme (you have to remove the windowActionBar false part from your theme).

if you want to use a toolbar, you have to ensure that there is a Toolbar view in your layouts.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

then you can use your code.

but you should also ensure that `getSupportActionBar()` does not return null before you use it. in case that the layout is missing the toolbar.

---

**OLD ANSWER BELOW**

---

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION here
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

you only set the toolbar if the view has been found. it seems that the view has not been found.

after the if you access the actionbar that has not been set and is therefore null.

also in your them you have `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` that disables the default actionbar.

you can do following:

- set `windowActionbar` to true in your theme then you have the default actionbar and you wont need the Toolbar.
- if you want to use your toolbar on a non default location you have to ensure that `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` actually returns a toolbar (check your layouts that there is a Toolbar with that id)
- or do not use getSupportActionBar without testing it for null.

Comment: also the actionbar provided by windowActionBar is a Toolbar. just that you don't have to take care of it.

Comment: well i don't knwo why the tutorial states to remove the windowActionBar. you only have to do that if you want to customize the position or size. if you want to use it as a simple actionbar like before 5.0 you dont need to remove it.

Comment: also to remove it one could just use the Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar theme as parent.

Comment: well. i think the tutorials state it like that, as the toolbar allows more customization if needed. fact is. you only need to disable the windowActionBar if you want to use a Toolbar instance as ActionBar. but again. if the op wants to disable the actionbar. he has to ensure that the Toolbar view is present in his layout. and to avoid the NPe if it is not present he has to null check getSupportActionBar before usage.

Comment: I set the "windowActionBar" element in my theme to true and commented out the Toolbar stuff from my code and it works fine.Yayayyaya :D Can you guys think of a reason why the Toolbar is not found by my app ? I definitely have a layout for it.

Comment: Sorry too late I deleted them. Think of validating the answer of @Dodge as the accepted answer and to +1 him also.

Comment: @DrkStr do you have the Toolbar in your XML used as theme for your activity? I reckon that you don't have it in the correct file and therefore it can not be found.

Comment: @DrkStr i just saw it. you have the toolbar xml stuff in a seperate file. add the code from toolbar.xml to your activity_main.xml (skip the `<?xml` line)

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked perfectly :D Cheers to you all.

Comment: I'm happy that we could help. It would be nice if you accept the answer. :)