# getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true), -> java.lang.NullPointerException Impossible to resolve

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

I have the following problem:
`getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I know that  there are many post with the same problem, but this one i can  resolve. I tried all  solution that  I found, but  no one  help  me, I work  this Fragment and Drawer (Android)

this  is the  code : MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.erik.test2;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        //---- Open Drawer on clic icon BUT CAUSE NULLPOINT EXEPTION--- //
       //*
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);//*/

        /*
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);//*/
//*
       mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer,  R.drawable.logo_tam, R.string.ouverture, R.string.fermeture) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.titre);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.titre_apres_ouverture);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); //*

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, R.drawable.logo_tam, R.string.ouverture, R.string.fermeture ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle("Fermer");
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle("Ouvert");
            }
        };
        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);*/

       // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Make sure this is the method with just `Bundle` as the signature
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

}
```

code of styles.xml (I already try to change theme  to  Theme.AppCompat.Light but it doesn't work)

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

code of toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Code activity_main.xml

```
<!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <!--  <include
              layout="@layout/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> -->

          <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and code  of manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.erik.test2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried many options with the Theme but it doesn't work in my ActivityMain in the comment you can see  all the tests that I tried.

Comment: you can use `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: remove comment form setSupportActionBar(toolbar); and then use getSupportActionBar()

Comment: Hi,   thx  for  this quickly answered.
i allready  tried but it doesn't work , i put it in comments  of MainActivity 

 ' getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); '

And  with  
`toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
`

Comment: @RSCP Solve yet ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859339/trouble-implementing-material-theme

Comment: I think you need not to use `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`  `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`  by removing it your drawer will work fine and use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`  in `onDrawerClosed` & `onDrawerOpened`

Comment: Use  `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two ways:
1. use `getSupportActionBar()` instead `getActionBar()`
2. change your activity to extend `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya and  MHP  thank you  so  much   i use  your answer and  now  it's work  good :
1)i remplace i MainActivity my activity by  'ActionBarActivity'
2)After i remplace getActionBar() ....  by 
 'if (getSupportActionBar() != null)'
        '{'
           'getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);'
            'getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);'
       ' }'
3)in the styles i use juste Theme.AppCompat.Light 
4)i delet 'toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);'

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated so its better to use AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya 's answer is too better

Answer (score 2):

**`Bad Approach`**

Use **deprecated** code . Avoid calling **ActionBarActivity** .

### Advice

> Since the version 22.1.0, the class ActionBarActivity is deprecated.
>   You should use AppCompatActivity.

You are getting

> getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment out this line **At First** .

```
<include
          layout="@layout/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**2ndly** , You can use `getSupportActionBar()` instead `getActionBar()` & add `null` checking

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
{
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

You can change your theme because you are using `NoActionBar`

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

> Using the Toolbar to replace an ActionBar is pretty straight forward
>   and begins with making sure that the activity extends
>   ActionBarActivity. Also make sure that the theme for this activity is
>   a child of either Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar or
>   Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

Please check **`#SO`** Answer **[What to use instead of getSupportActionBar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899311/what-to-use-instead-of-getsupportactionbar-in-library-22)**

and

> https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: your answer is better but I think you should also add `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` before call `getSupportActionBar()`

Answer (score 1):

**getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);** is giving **NullPointerException** because in your styles.xml you have given parent **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** which means there is no ActionBar.

**Solution:**

Change your **style** with the style given below in your **styles.xml**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Now in your MainAcitivity use this code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

do it in this way

```
    // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Find our drawer view
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

    //---- Open Drawer on clic icon BUT CAUSE NULLPOINT EXEPTION--- //

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

also change your layout

```
<!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
    <include
          layout="@layout/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

      <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
<!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    />
```

Comment: I have just  try  it but  the same pb
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.erik.test2/com.example.erik.test2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 ......
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
                                                       at ....`

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting action bar, uncomment following code from your xml.

```
   <!--  <include
              layout="@layout/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> -->
```

Also use default theme currently you are using NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

You are using `AppCompat`.So, use this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `AppCompactActivity` which is  in support library. so you need to get ActionBar instance using `getSupportActionBar()`

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Since you have given NoActionBar theme. uncomment the toolbar include related you need to add toolbar.Either give Theme with ActionBar not NoActionBar. or Give Toolbar in layout and add it.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
           <include
              layout="@layout/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  

          <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```